# Capybara Not Logging in via Simple_Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, simple-form

I'm having trouble with a test I've written that is working fine when I do it in Chrome, but my test suite says otherwise.

Here are my tests:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'user can sign in' do
  let(:customer) { FactoryGirl.create(:customer) }
  it 'allows users to sign in directly' do
    visit new_customer_session_path
    fill_in 'Email', with: customer.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: customer.password 
    click_button('Sign in')
    expect(page).to have_content('Signed in successfully')
  end
  it 'allows users to sign in via the home page' do
    visit root_path
    click_link('Sign in')
    fill_in 'Email', with: customer.email, match: :prefer_exact
    fill_in 'Password', with: customer.password 
    click_button('Sign in')
    expect(page).to have_content('Signed in successfully')
  end
  it 'only when valid fields are entered' do
    visit root_path
    click_link('Sign in')
    click_button('Sign in')
    expect(page).to have_content("Invalid email or password")
  end
end
```

All of these result in either:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Signed in successfully')
       expected to find text "Signed in successfully"
```

or

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("Invalid email or password")
       expected to find text "Invalid email or password"
```

I thought that was weird so when I try and login myself in development mode, I see my flash messages as such:

[image: bootstrap flash msg]

My form looks like this:

```
      <%= simple_form_for(resource,
                          as: resource_name,
                          url: session_path(resource_name),
                          html: { class: 'form-horizontal' },
                          wrapper: :horizontal_form,
                          wrapper_mappings: {
                            check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
                            radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
                            file: :horizontal_file_input,
                            boolean: :horizontal_boolean
                          }) do |f| %>
                          <%= f.input :email, reqiured: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email" %>
                          <%= f.input :password, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Password" %>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="login-c2">
                        <div class="logmargfix">
                          <div class="chpadding50">
                            <div class="alignbottom">
                              <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in", class: 'btn-search4' %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="alignbottom2">
                              <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
       <% end %>
```

Here's what I know, previously my form was just the standard simple_form generated by `rails generate devise:views`.  The below form makes all my tests pass... so what have I done in the code above that is breaking capybara?

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: false, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: false %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
  </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render "customers/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: for the first example, try filling in the form like this `fill_in 'user_email'..fill_in 'user_password'`. You have to inspect the fields though, I just assume that's what is generated. Also, for sanity check, after sign in, do `expect(page).to have_content('Email')` to see in what page you are on.

Comment: @PNY thanks for the comment.  I tried changing one test to `fill_in 'customer_email'` but that didn't change anything.  I don't think the `Sign in` button is getting clicked correctly.  The HTML generated for that button via simple_form is `<input class="btn btn-default btn-search4" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in">`

Comment: Above you have `click_button('Sign in')`. I believe in order for Capybara to click a button with a particular `value` you need to do `click('Sign in')`

Comment: When I change it to just `click` I get `Failure/Error: click('Sign in')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `click' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserCanSignIn:0x0000010a4bc958>`

Comment: can you find it? `find_button('Sign in')`

Comment: The code doesn't explode when it tries to click "Sign in" - therefore it is finding that button. it could be that capybara isn't waiting properly... try adding `expect(page).to have_content("Sign out")` just before the check for the flash... after all - it should definitely have the signout link on the page.

Comment: @TarynEast well this is surprising, it's NOT showing 'Sign Out'.  I still see in the header "Login or Sign up".  How is that possible?  I can login myself via the same steps but Capybara can't.  I'm stumped

Comment: Time for `puts` statements in the authentication method? :)

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast - I've been playing with it today and I've got some more bizarre news.  The standard simple_form sign_in view works just fine, it's my custom one above that's causing capybara to break.

Comment: silly idea... but you have no labels in your form. Try `fill_in 'email'` (lowercase) ? (even if just to rule it out)